# A Color/Shape detection mechanism for Augmented Reality

Tags: computer-vision, augmented-reality

Is there a very basic color/shape detection mechanism through which one could detect a specific color or a shape in a webcam feed? Wanted to use the color/or shape as a symbolic marker for an AR application.
Though the ideal case would be a NFT  , but i am not much of coder and have no experience in OpenCV( have read a lot about it in previous discussions here).Have worked so far with the SLAR tooolkit only and that offers only the basic b/w marker detection
And the more easily useable NFT libraries are , well, not freeware :/

Any guidance to integrate the abovementioned detection routines in a .Net/Flash environment would be of great help.

Comment: StackExchange proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30436/augmented-reality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color detection is very easy: take your videostream images, convert them to binary images by using the RGB value as a vector (like RGB = [0,255,0] = green), and setting other vectors within a given distance as positive hits.  This is one of the easiest forms of computer vision, and a couple of early CV-based PS2 games involved detecting brightly colored props.

[This is my favorite paper](http://www.hitlabnz.org/publications/2009-Shape_Recognition_and_Pose_Estimation_for_Mobile_Augmented_Reality.pdf) on shape recognition - if you want to detect simple 2D outlines on flat surfaces, this is a great technique.

I'm neither a .Net or a Flash programmer, so I can't offer any help there.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Had a look at various color detection examples- the ones that detect faces using Skin color RGb, tracking colored objects etc. It could be something to start upon. The Shape recognition paper was a treat to read- I've used ARToolkit from HITLab, and if something like Nestor comes along it could make life very easy. However the shape recogniton seems to be a lot of in-depth CV and image analysis , at least for someone like me with no CV experience.  Dont think I can put off OpenCV lessons any longer :)